# How to make squid accept requests over HTTPS?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have an issue with my provider. Some sites don't work (time out). Most notably, gravatar.com. I have a browser extension in mind that allows to proxy some requests. The thing is, proxies that come with it don't allow to proxy gravatar.com. And free proxies I specify doesn't work (in the browser). The thing I noticed is that free proxies work this way:

```
https_proxy=http://ip:port curl 'https://www.gravatar.com'
```

But not this way:

```
https_proxy=https://ip:port curl 'https://www.gravatar.com'
```

I tried `tinyproxy`, now `squid`, to no avail. I tried following [this tutorial](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/SslBumpExplicit), but `squid` says: "Bungled /etc/squid3/squid.conf line 1617: http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid3/myCA.pem". I'm not too concerned about it being specifically `squid`. What do I do?

On a side note, is the following correct? `https_proxy` variable is for requests to https sites, but communication with proxy depends on the value (`https_proxy=http://...` or `https_proxy=https://...`)?

Comment: I suspect installing a Squid proxy on your side might not improve the situation. Try a remote VPN. I have done tests with limited success with people in Maputo, Manila and Phnom Penh. It really improved their quality. Have a look at some commercial offerings, it might be worth the money.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm trying to setup a proxy on a remote server, where gravatar.com works.